Understand and applying updating formula for MARS (multivariate adaptive regression splines)
I am reading through the MARS paper (http://www.stat.yale.edu/~lc436/08Spring665/Mars_Friedman_91.pdf) and I am trying to understand and implement the update formula in eq 52. But I have a difficult time understanding it.
It starts in eq 48 when he wants us to use the covariance matrix for the normal equation instead of just $B^T B$ but the matrix $V$ in equation 48 isn't even SPD so a cholesky decomposition that he suggest shouldn't work?
How should I understand the logic of going from equation 47 (which is just the naive slow way to solve for the coefficients) to 48 and possibly 49. Any help is much appreciated.

Please paste in whatever context is necessary to
understand & answer your question. We want this thread to
remain valuable even if the link goes dead.
